# Imprimir dados de um dicionário em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

Como eu faço para imprimir os dados de um dicionário cada um em uma coluna?

Por exemplo:

```
lanchonete = {"Salgado":4.50, "Lanche":6.50,"Suco":3.00,"Refrigerante":3.50,"Doce":1.00}

for m in lanchonete:
    print (m[0])
```

Eu quero imprimir os lanches numa coluna e os valores em outra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma iteração com `for` num dicionário sempre itera só sobre as chaves - por isso você não viu os valores.

Dicionários, no entanto, além de serem iteráveis diretamente tem três métodos que devolvem iteradores especializados: sobre as chaves (`.keys()`), sobre os valores (`.values()`) ou sobre ambos (`.items()`) - esse último método devolve as chaves e valores sequências de dois items (tuplas)  - e pode ser usado com o augmented assignemnt de Python que permite que várias variáveis  recebam os valores de items de uma sequência.

Então dá pra fazer assim:

```
lanchonete = {"Salgado":4.50, "Lanche":6.50,"Suco":3.00,"Refrigerante":3.50,"Doce":1.00}
for produto, preco in lanchonete.items():
     print(produto, preco)
```

Se você quiser agregar mai sinformações ao que estiver imprimindo, uma boa pedida são as f-strings, que existem a partir do Python 3.6:

```
for produto, preco in lanchonete.items():
     print(f"Produto {produto}: R${preco:0.02f}")
```

Comment: Poxa. Agradeço a ajuda. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 6):

Tem várias formas de fazer isto, uma delas seria assim:

```
lanchonete = {"Salgado" : 4.5, "Lanche" : 6.5, "Suco" : 3, "Refrigerante" : 3.5, "Doce" : 1}
for item in lanchonete:
    print("{0:20} {1:6.2f}".format(item, lanchonete[item]))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hU5eoU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vpxbaagd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/DictKeyValue.py).

Desta forma está usando a função [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html) para montar a linha fazendo o *padding* do texto e a correta formatação do número também fazendo i *padding* e colocando no formato apropriado (que eu achei melhor).

Comment: Muito obrigado. Me ajudou muito.